# "not done yet" Exception when running FHIR Validator

Tags: hl7-fhir

I downloaded the Jar File for the FHIR Validator. Then I ran the Validator as per the instructions on the HL7 Website. I ran the following command from cmd:

java -jar org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar Composition.xml -defn validation-min.xml.zip

I downloaded both the resource file and the validation package on the desktop. But I get the following error

```
java -Xmx512m -jar org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar Composit
ion.xml -defn validation.xml.zip
  .. load definitions from validation.xml.zip
  .. connect to terminology server http://fhir-dev.healthintersections.com.au/op
en
  .. load Composition.xml
  .. validate (xml)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: not done yet
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.utils.SimpleWorkerContext.validateCode(SimpleWo
rkerContext.java:282)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.InstanceValidator.checkCodeableConce
pt(InstanceValidator.java:219)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.InstanceValidator.validateElement(In
stanceValidator.java:1801)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.InstanceValidator.start(InstanceVali
dator.java:1238)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.InstanceValidator.validateResource(I
nstanceValidator.java:1868)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.InstanceValidator.validate(InstanceV
alidator.java:1344)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.InstanceValidator.validate(InstanceV
alidator.java:1281)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.ValidationEngine.processXml(Validati
onEngine.java:195)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.ValidationEngine.process(ValidationE
ngine.java:117)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.Validator.process(Validator.java:173
)
        at org.hl7.fhir.instance.validation.Validator.main(Validator.java:102)
```

NOTE: I added Xmx512m because I constantly get out of memory error without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for taking so long to answer - I had to do the bit that wasn't done, and it turned into a big rewrite. I've done that now. If you download from the current build, instead of DSTU2 - as long as the major and minor versions are the same - then that will work

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort. I will download the current build from here (https://hl7-fhir.github.io/downloads.html) and then will see if it works, though I didn't understand by what you meant by "as long as the major and minor versions are the same". I also have other questions with regards to the Validator. For instance, when  I tried using the jar with eclipse and tried running it, it asks for a src but I only have jar, so where can I get the source to it? But I don't know whether I should open a separate thread for each question regarding the validator.

Comment: All the source is in the FHIR gForge SVN (http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir) under \build\implementations\java